# Как правильно задать правило для умного фильтра Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Не понимаю как выстроить путь,
Путь до фильтра https://zooset.test/manufacturers/ed6a3948-02e4-11ea-80c9-cb4ec39ec3cd/
Тоесть я зашел в каталог и подраздел.
В SEF_RULE (в редактировании компонента умного фильтра) пишу - /manufacturers/#SECTION_CODE#/filter/#SMART_FILTER_PATH#/apply/
И он строит такой путь:
https://zooset.test/manufacturers/filter/cml2_manufacturer-is-0117a7fc-e9a4-11e9-80c9-cb4ec39ec3cd/apply/